# How to change color of the sticky column when the table was scrolled and column stuck to the border

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a help with my sticky column. It's a second column in the table and I want it to change color from white to light grey when the table has been scrolled and the column became fixed on the left. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.rtable td:nth-child(2)').position().left >= 2) {
    $('.rtable td:nth-child(2)').css("background", "rgba(216, 212, 212, 0.9)");
  }
});
```

```css
.rtable {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.rtable td:nth-child(2),
.rtable th:nth-child(2) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 2px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table categories-table rtable">
  <tr>
    <th><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox"> </th>
    <th>Hashtag</th>
    <th>IC</th>
    <th>Posts</th>
    <th>LL</th>
    <th>HL</th>
    <th>ML</th>
    <th>LC</th>
    <th>HC</th>
    <th>MC</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>#fitnessfun</td>
    <td>
      <div class="ic-circle circle-orange"></div>
    </td>
    <td>1.182.568</td>
    <td>268</td>
    <td>3.343</td>
    <td>643</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>259</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, I'll be grateful if you help to set the border to the sticky column. When I write border property it's shown in the table in the place the column used to be, but when the column slides any border disappears 
Thank you!

Comment: FYI you have a syntax error as `=>` needs to be `>=`

Comment: the Syntax error You can show the true here : https://jsfiddle.net/to53jbe5/2/

Comment: Thank you, I improved the syntax error, but still, it doesn't work the way I want. It makes my column grey at once and I want it to become grey only when it stuck to the left, so at the beginning it should be white. I guess it's just I have the wrong script written

Comment: You need to set Border around the table or what

Comment: I need to make a border around the sticky column when it has fixed position